# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine when using a tor proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, httpwebrequest, tor

I'm trying to send an httpwebrequest using a tor proxy with my asp.net application and I receive this error message when calling the webresponse.GetResponse() method:

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

I've tried searching for a solution on the web and I found 3 main solutions for this error:

1. Add to Web.config.

   ```
   <system.net>
     <settings>
       <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
     </settings>
   </system.net>`
   ```
2. Add the line: `webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;` to the code.
3. Add the line `request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` to the code.

Each one of the listed solutions didn't change a thing about the error message.

Here's the request code:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebRequest("127.0.0.1:9051");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19";

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
webResponse.Close();
return html;
```

Can anyone help me find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can get more details about the exception you are getting which is actually a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztey1y5b) by looking at the `Response` property of the exception and then checking the `StatusDescription` and `StatusCode` properties. That will help you get more details about the error and hopefully point you in the right direction.

Something like this:

```
    catch(WebException e) 
    {
        if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
        }
    }
```

Also, take a look at [WebException.Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status) example on MSDN to get more details

Comment: I tried adding these lines but the status isn't a protocol error but ServerProtocolViolation.

Comment: Indeed, the Response is null for my exception :(

Comment: Same problem here. The Response is null.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  httpwebrequest getresponse method always return error protocol vialotion and i solved probled this way ;

first of all i use xml com object instead of xdocument or xmldocument.

this com object's have a few version Microsft XML , v3.0-v5.0-v6.0. i used v6.0.

```
MSXML2.DOMDocument60Class doc = new MSXML2.DOMDocument60Class();
doc.setProperty("ServerHTTPRequest",true);
doc.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false); 
doc.async = false;
doc.load(extURL);  

if (doc.parseError.errorCode != 0)
{
 // error  
}
else
{
 // do stuff
}
```