# Error when Parsing RSS

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, rss

I 'm trying to parse RSS feeds and then display them on my website. My code seems to work correctly when parsing techcrunch & arstechnica RSS. But when I try to parse HackerNews [RSS](http://news.ycombinator.com/rss) I get the an error.

```
    XmlReader readXML;
    readXML = XmlReader.Create(GetURL());
    SyndicationFeed News= SyndicationFeed.Load(readXML);
    readXML.Close();
    return News;
```

I get the following error on  **readXML = XmlReader.Create(GetURL());**  geturl is the url for rss.

---

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

---

Any suggestions why I 'm getting the above error.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674938/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-when-using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link:

[The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine](http://forums.asp.net/t/1155887.aspx/1)

1.) You can add the following `<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />` in the Web Config file to solve the server committed a protocol violation

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
</settings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

2.)

**Attention to all web developers who are using Skype! Make sure to uncheck the option for using port 80 and 443 from Tools\Options\Connection dialog.**

[image]